Operation on a group determines the group?
I am trying to work on Problem 2.2:2 of Bergman's An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions:
Consider a group $(G, \mu, \iota, e)$. Write $\mu(a,b)$ as $a\cdot b$ and suppose $\delta : G \to G$ is a map such that for all $a, b \in G$,
$$
    \delta(a, b) = a\cdot\iota(b).
$$
Does $(G, \delta)$ determine the group $(G, \mu, \iota, e)$? That is if $(G_1, \mu_1, \iota_1, e_1)$ and $(G_2, \mu_2, \iota_2, e_2)$ yield the same pair $(G'_1, \delta_1) = (G'_2, \delta_2)$, then must $(G_1, \mu_1, \iota_1, e_1) = (G_2, \mu_2, \iota_2, e_2)$? (page 12 of the linked pdf)
How does one go about proving this? In particular, I feel that since we have defined $\delta$ in terms of $\iota: G \times G \to G$ and $\mu$, saying '$(G, \delta)$ determines $(G, \mu,\iota,e)$' looks circular to me (but maybe I am missing the point completely). What is this trying to illustrate?
Here is my attempt:
Suppose $(G, \mu, \iota, e)$ is a group and let $(G, \delta)$ be defined as above. Let $(G', \mu', \iota', e')$ be another group and let $(G', \delta')$ be similarly defined.
Now suppose $(G, \delta) = (G' \delta')$, i.e., $G = G'$ and for all $a, b \in G = G'$ we have
$$
\delta(a, b) = a \cdot \iota(b) = a * \iota'(b) = \delta'(a, b).
$$
where $\mu(a, b) = a \cdot b$ and $\mu'(a', b') = a' * b'$.
Now observe that
$$
e = a \cdot \iota(a) = \delta(a, a) = \delta'(a, a) = a * \iota'(a) = e'.
$$
Let $a \in G = G'$ and let $\alpha = \iota(a)$ and $\alpha' = \iota'(a)$. Then in $G$ we have by the equality of $e$ and $e'$
$$
\iota(a) = e \cdot \iota(a) = \delta(e, a) = \delta'(e, a) = e * \iota'(a) = \iota'(a)
$$
and
$$
 \iota'(a) = e' * \iota'(a) = \delta'(e', a) = \delta(e',a) = e' \cdot \iota(a) = \iota(a).
$$
Finally, we have
$$
a \cdot b = \delta(a, \iota(b)) = \delta'(a, \iota(b)) = a * \iota'(\iota(b))
$$
but then by the equality of inverses it follows that
$$
 a * \iota'(\iota(b)) = a * \iota'(\iota'(b)) = a * b.
$$
This shows that $(G, \mu, \iota, e) = (G', \mu', \iota', e')$.

It's not circular: the bit after "that is" tells you what it means explicitly. One usually goes further and adds that such a $\delta$ operation satisfying certain axioms yields a group which yields back the same $\delta$. Together, these properties are saying that the set of group structures on $G$ is in bijection with the set of "$\delta$-structures" on $G$: they are equivalent structures to equip a set with.

@NaïmFavier - thanks for the answer! I am unclear about the part where you say `$\delta$ operation satisfying certain axioms.' Should I take that to mean that the group structure of $G$ determines these $\delta$ operations and these $\delta$ operations determine the structure in $G$? Then can I conclude from that statement that the group structure on a set $G$ is uniquely determined by the group operation we define on it (precisely because of these $\delta$ operations)?

I am not seeing the connection you're making, but the structure of a group is entirely determined by the group operation (because the other stuff are properties), independently of the alternative presentation in terms of $\delta$.

Following Bergman's notation, a group is a $4$-tuple $G=(|G|,\mu,\iota,e)$, where $|G|$ is the underlying set of $G$, $\mu\colon |G|\times|G|\to|G|$ is a binary operation, $\iota\colon |G|\to|G|$ is a unary operation, $e\colon \varnothing\to|G|$ is a nullary operation, and we have that:

$\forall x,y,z\in|G| (\mu(x,\mu(y,z)) = \mu(\mu(x,y),z)$ (associativity of $\mu$);
$\forall x\in|G| (\mu(e,x) = \mu(x,e) = x)$ (the nullary operation identifies the identity element);
$\forall x\in |G| \mu(\iota(x),x) = \mu(x,\iota(x))=e$ ($\iota$ gives inverses).

The problem is to show that if $G=(|G|,\mu,\iota,e)$ is a group; and $G'=(|G|',\mu',\iota',e')$ is also a group, and we define binary operations $\delta_G$ on $G$ by $\delta_G(x,y) = \mu(x,\iota(y))$, and similarly for $\delta_{G'}$, and we have that $(|G|,\delta_G) = (|G'|,\delta_{G'})$ (equality, not merely isomorphism), then it must follow that $G=G'$ (again, equality, not just isomorphism); that is, that $(|G|,\mu,\iota,e) = (|G'|,\mu',\iota',e')$.
As you note, from $(|G|,\delta_G) = (|G'|,\delta_{G'})$, we conclude that $|G|=|G|'$. We can then show that the nullary operations $e$ and $e'$ are equal, because $e=\delta_G(x,x)$ for any $x\in X$, and $e'=\delta_{G'}(x',x')$ for any $x'\in X$. But if $\delta_G=\delta_{G'}$, then picking any $x\in |G|=|G'|$ we get
$$e = \delta_G(x,x) = \delta_{G'}(x,x) = e',$$
so the nullary operations agree. Then we can show that $\iota=\iota'$ because for any $x\in |G|=|G'|$ we have
$$\iota(x) = \delta_G(e,x) = \delta_{G'}(e',x) = \iota'(x),$$
so $\iota=\iota'$ as functions. And finally, $\mu=\mu'$ as functions since for all $x,y\in |G|=|G'|$ we have
$$\mu(x,y) = \mu(x,\iota(\iota(y))) = \delta_G(x,\iota(y)) = \delta_{G'}(x,\iota'(y)) = \mu'(x,\iota'(\iota'(y))) = \mu'(x,y),$$
so $\mu=\mu'$ as functions.
Thus, if $(|G|,\delta_G) = (|G|',\delta_{G'})$, then $G=G'$. Informally, knowing the set $|G|$ and knowing the operation $\delta_g(x,y) = xy^{-1}$ tells you exactly what the group is. So if you are given a set $|G|$, the operation $\delta_G$, and you know that $|G|$ is the underlying set of a group and that $\delta_G$ is the operation derived form that group structure by $\delta_G(x,y) = \mu(x,\iota(y))$, then you can determine exactly who $\mu$, $\iota$, and $e$ are in the group $G=(|G|,\mu,\iota,e)$.
Contrast this with the situation in a similar exercise in that section, where we define the operation $\rho_G(x,y) = xyx^{-1}$. And the question then is whether given groups $G$ and $G'$, if $(|G|,\rho_G) = (|G'|,\rho_{G'})$, will it follow that $G=G'$? The answer here is "no", because you can take a set $|G|$ with four elements, let $G$ be the cyclic group of order $4$ with underlying set $|G|$, and let $G'$ be the Klein $4$-group with underlying set $|G|$. Then $\rho_G$ and $\rho_{G'}$ are both the projection onto the second argument, $\rho_G(x,y) = \rho_{G'}(x,y) = y$, but the groups $G$ and $G'$ are not equal (not even isomorphic).  So even though $(|G|,\rho_G) = (|G'|,\rho_{G'})$, we do not have $(|G|,\mu,\iota,e) = (|G'|,\mu',\iota',e')$ (or even an isomorphism).
So if you are given a set $|G|$, and you know it is the underlying set of a group, and you are given the operation $\rho_G$, the pair $(|G|,\rho_G)$ does not allow you to determine the group $G=(|G|,\mu,\iota,\rho)$. This operation does not "determine" the group the same way that $\delta_G$ does.

Apologies for the delayed response. Thank you for this answer, really helped my intuition!
